# How to encode/decode charset encoding in NodeJS?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, node.js

I have this code :

```
request({ url: 'http://www.myurl.com/' }, function(error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log($('title', html).text());
  }
});
```

But the websites that Im crawling can have different charset (utf8, iso-8859-1, etc..) how to get it and encode/decode the html always to the right encoding (utf8) ?

Thanks and sorry for my english ;)

Comment: Well I know that I can use the option `encoding` for the request but the problem I dont know yet the charset of the page (that I know with the header or the meta tag)

Answer (score 2):

The website could return the content encoding in the content-type header or the content-type meta tag inside the returned HTML, eg:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=latin1"/>
```

You can use the [charset](https://github.com/fengmk2/charset) module to automatically check both of these for you. Not all websites or servers will specify an encoding though, so you'll want to fall back to detecting the charset from the data itself. The [jschardet](https://github.com/aadsm/jschardet) module can help you with that.

Once you've worked out the charset you can use the iconv module to do the actual conversion. Here's a full example:

```
request({url: 'http://www.myurl.com/', encoding: 'binary'}, function(error, response, html) {
    enc = charset(response.headers, html)
    enc = enc or jchardet.detect(html).encoding.toLowerCase()
    if enc != 'utf-8'
        iconv = new Iconv(enc, 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE')
        html = iconv.convert(new Buffer(html, 'binary')).toString('utf-8')
    console.log($('title', html).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First up, you could send an *Accept-Charset* header which would prevent websites from sending data in other charsets.

Once you get a response, you can check the *Content-Type* header for the *charset* entry and do appropriate processing.

Anothr hack (I've used in the past) when the content encoding is unknown is try to decode using all possible content encodings and stick to the one that doesn't throw an exception (using in python though).

Comment: You can also try the module announced on this page: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/38dc4444b2e1436c and here's the directi link: https://github.com/franzenzenhofer/whatlang